# Two different processor write to single writer in Java Spring batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

[image: two different processor write to a single writer]

I have two different Reader that read from different tables and i have process those data and converted to required dto object.

I want to write a file with the two dto objects.

Please give me hand to resolve this...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the code of what you have tried?

Comment: @ŠimonKocúrek Currently I have a code logic with two different reader process and write to a different files. but I want some of the data from first processor and some of the data from second processor.

actually is that possible at all in spring ?

Comment: How is the data correlated? Perhaps a composite item reader would work in this case.

Comment: No the data are different... so composite item reader wont work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that in a single chunk-oriented step. You need to stage items in an intermediate storage and create a second step that reads from the intermediate storage and write to the final file.

The intermediate storage can be a staging table or queue for example. You can also write items in intermediate files then merge those files.

Comment: Thanks @Ben... I have created the two steps and stored the first processor data to an static object and used it in another step's processor.